# Understanding Normal Force Change

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

*I know this has been asked around, my question is a bit more specialized towards my personal problem.*

If I have an object the magnitude of the weight is usually equal to the normal force, right?

I could be mistaken but from what I have read the normal force is the force the object is feeling opposite to the $(mass*gravity)$. If that is the case, and I put my hand on the object does my Force get added to the object's weight and thus the normal force of that object increases? Therefore if I keep adding hands to the object will the normal force keep compensating?

Also is the normal force the negative charged electrons repelling each other (electromagnetism)?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It will held and normal force will keep on compensating until the object on which the object lies experience so much force by newton's third law that it will break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be exact, the normal force is such as to enforce the motion constraint of the object. If you have a static case, then the normal force is such that the sum of forces equals zero.

$$-F+N-W=0 \\ N = W+F$$